# inserting data to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, drop-down-menu

What I am trying to do is this: When I select color from dropdown list, it will be submited to database and into *car* table. I have already setup the database.

This is part of the HTML code.

```
<form  action="rinnad.php" method="post">
Car color:
<select name="Rinnad"> 
<option>red</option>  
<option>blue</option> 
<option>green</option> 
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="lisa" />
</form>
```

Here is the PHP code that I am using to enter car color into database:

```
 <?php
$connect = @mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die("Fail!!!! :D:D:D");
mysql_select_db("tibid") or die("there is no such db");
if($connect){   
    echo "connected to db";
}else{
    echo "didnt connect to db"; 
}
$car = "red"
$query = mysql_query("insert into test values('','$car')"); 
?>
```

What do I need to do?
Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Pekka All cars seem to be red :) But I agree that an actual question or problem description would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to assign values to the options:

```
<option value="red">red</option>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp

After that your need to assign the value from the form to your $car variable:

```
$car = $_POST['Rinnad'];
```

or, more securely, with some protection against SQL-injections:

```
$car = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Rinnad']);
```

Comment: As I've recently learned, [w3schools may best be avoided...](http://w3fools.com/) :)

Comment: was missing $rinnad = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Rinnad']); Worked very well thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the eye opener djacobson :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a ; after this line

```
$car = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get the posted value:

```
$car = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Rinnad']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You got an error with

```
$car = "red";
$query = mysql_query("insert into test values('','$car')");
```

Here you did'nt specify the fieldname to which $car specifies.i thnk u gave the auto_increment for car id..??
thn Your code will be

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into test (color)values('$car')");
```

you neednot specify the auto increment field.default it can be added.